# jquery bubbling up unknown error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that copies text into a hidden input and submits it to redraw parts of the page.

```
function searchHelp() {
  // Copy value to hidden input
  jQuery('input.searchInput').bind('change paste keyup', function() {
    jQuery('.hide.searchBox').val(jQuery(this).val());
  });
  // Get the current page name
  var pageName = window.location.pathname;
  pageName = pageName.split("/").pop();

  if(pageName === 'blu_search') {
    jQuery(".searchBox input").keypress(function(event) {
      console.log("Inside keypress");
      if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery(".hide.searchSubmit").click();
      }
    });
    jQuery(".searchSubmit").on("click", function() {
      jQuery(".hide.searchSubmit").click();
      console.log("hidden button clicked");
    });
  } else {
    jQuery(".searchBox input").keypress(function(event) {
      if(event.which === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery(".searchSubmit").click();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In the console I get
[image]

The specific line that causes the error is `jQuery(".hide.searchSubmit").click();`. When I comment this line the code runs without any errors. Does anyone know why this or how to trouble shoot this type of error?

**EDIT**: Here is the error expanded out. I was not able to get all of in one go. Here is a paste of the entire output, http://pastebin.com/hSYnRskB

[image]

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Please post your HTML too.

Comment: I would guess it's an infinite loop error?

Comment: I added the output of the error and also a paste of the entire error. I believe it might be an infinite loop also but I am not able to figure out why it would be in a loop at all.

Comment: Looking at the expanded error, it almost certainly is an issue with the infinite loop you're creating, as your handler for ".searchSubmit" onclick then clicks ".searchSubmit", looping forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with an infinite loop error.

```
jQuery(".searchSubmit").on("click",function(){...}) //Click handler (part1)
```

This callback function will run any time an element with the class `searchSubmit` is clicked

Inside that function (what is run when it is clicked) you do:

```
jQuery(".hide.searchSubmit").click(); //Click trigger (part2)
```

Which then triggers `part1`, which then fires `part2`, etc etc etc

To fix this you can either restructure how you're handling this functionality, use completely different classes for different states, or just change the `.click()` line to:

```
if(jQuery(this).hasClass("hide") === false)
{
    jQuery(".hide.searchSubmit").click();
}
```

(or something to that effect)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a click just use [trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
jQuery(".sel").trigger("click");
```

Moreover this could cause errors

```
jQuery(".searchSubmit").on("click", function() {
      jQuery(".hide.searchSubmit").click();
      console.log("hidden button clicked");
    });
```